# How to Enter the Date Manually in UWP Calendar?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am working on a UWP (Universal Windows Platform) application on Windows 10 and I can't manually enter the date in `CalendarDatePicker`.

How can I enter the date manually, with out selecting from the calendar, by using `CalendarDatePicker` in an UWP app?

Comment: `CalendarDatePicker` does not allow manual input, if you want to have user input then I would suggest creating your custom control inherited from CalendarDatePicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own [`Flyout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout) which would consist of a `Calendar` and `TextBox` so you could then pick a date as well as manually enter it. Those two controls can then be data-bound together so that selection in one will update the other.

The main advantage of using `CalendarDatePicker` directly is that it automatically adapts to the current culture of the user, so the format will always be familiar to her. This is something you have to be mindful of with the `TextBox` - to parse the input based on the current culture of the user.